# Как выполнить запрос на обновление с использованием данных из запроса или другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, access

У меня такой вопрос, использую СУБД MS Access. По заданию:

`Увеличить оклад на 1000 сотрудникам, имеющим более 2 несовершеннолетних детей.`

Таблица выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть запрос, который считает количество несовершеннолетних детей у каждого сотрудника, а вот построить запрос на обновление не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может может кто-то подсказать, как правильно построить запрос на обновление с использованием данных из другой таблицы (или возможно использование данных из запроса)

Comment: *как правильно построить запрос на обновление с использованием данных из другой таблицы* В построителе запросов использовать этот запрос как таблицу. Добавить в источник данных и связать по правильным полям. И добавить условие отбора по количеству детей, само собой. PS. Запрос на получение количества несовершеннолетних детей - неправильный.

Comment: Я пробовала использовать запрос как таблицы, предварительно связав их между собой, но не получалось. Может из-за того, что этот запрос неправильно сделала. Не подскажете как сделать верно?